# UseContext React: Data doesn't transfer from Login component to SideBar component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state, react-state-management

I'm trying to use a context in my react project but i dont know why the component "SideBar" can't update the context. The user flow is a user and passwrod simple form in the Login component and if the credentials are valid i want to display the username in the sidebar of my dashboard, as you see this is nothing fancy.

## index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { UserProvider } from './contexts/user.context';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserProvider>
        <App />
      </UserProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

## App.jsx

```js
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './routes/home/Home.component';
import Login from './routes/auth/Login.component';

import Dashboard from './components/Usuarios/UsuarioValid/MainColumn/Dashboard.component';

import Infrastructura from './components/Usuarios/Anonimo/MainColumn/Infrastructura.component';
import EquipoDirectivo from './components/Usuarios/Anonimo/MainColumn/EquipoDirectivo.component';
import AsignaturasRamas from './components/Usuarios/Anonimo/MainColumn/AsignaturasRamas.component';



const App = () => {

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />

      <Route path="anonimo" element={<Home isAnonimo />} >
        <Route index element={<Infrastructura />} />
        <Route path="equipo" element={<EquipoDirectivo/>} />
        <Route path="asignaturas" element={<AsignaturasRamas/>} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Home isAnonimo={false} />} >
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App;
```

## Home.component.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

import Sidebar from '../../components/Usuarios/UsuarioValid/Sidebar.component';
import TransitionRoot from '../../components/Usuarios/UsuarioValid/TransitionRoot.component';

import SidebarAnonimo from '../../components/Usuarios/Anonimo/SidebarAnonimo.component';
import TransitionRootAnonimo from '../../components/Usuarios/Anonimo/TransitionRootAnonimo.component';

const Home = (props) => {
    const { isAnonimo } = props;

    return (
        <>
            { 
                isAnonimo ? (
                    <div>
                        <TransitionRootAnonimo />
                        <SidebarAnonimo />
                        <Outlet />
                    </div>
            ) 
            : (
                <div>
                    <TransitionRoot />
                    <Sidebar />
                    <Outlet />
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

## user.context.jsx

```js
import { createContext, useState} from "react";



// Actual value we want to access
export const UserContext = createContext({
    currentUser: null,
    setCurrentUser: (x) => x,
});


// Used in route file (index.js) to handle context
export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const value = { currentUser, setCurrentUser };


    return <UserContext.Provider value={value}> {children} </UserContext.Provider>
}
```

## login.component.jsx

```js
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from '../../contexts/user.context';

const Login = () => {
const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useContext(UserContext)

    const [ formFields, setFormFields ] = useState(defaultFormFields);
    const { usuario, password } = formFields;
    const [ validCredentials, setValidCredentials ] = useState(true);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const usuariValid  = usuarios.find(u => 
            u.usuario === usuario 
            && u.contraseña === password
        );
        if(usuariValid){
            setCurrentUser(usuariValid);
            console.log(currentUser)
            /* window.location.replace('/dashboard'); */
        } else {
            resetFormFields();
            setValidCredentials(false);
            console.info("Credenciales invalidas");
        }
    };
/*NOT RELEVANT CODE*/
```

## sidebar.component.jsx

```js
*
import { UserContext } from '../../../contexts/user.context'
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext, Fragment} from 'react'

const Sidebar = () => {

  const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [idAsignaturas, setIdAsignaturas] = useState([]);
  const [nombreAsignaturas, setNombreAsignaturas] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{ console.log(currentUser},[currentUser]) /*OUTPUT:null*/
/*NOT RELEVANT CODE*/
}*
```

Comment: Hi, could you give more details about the problem? For example, attach the errors in the console. Remember to wrap those components (Login, Sidebar) with the UserContextProvider, in order to have access to the properties.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I try to login a user with the "Login" component and when I check that the user exists I want to update it in the context. But when I check that the user is correct and I execute the method to update the context and I change the location of the route to the dashboard where the sidebar is, and the context is not updated.

I do not receive errors in the console, we only receive "null" as a result of the console log that we use in the sidebar to check if the context is up to date.

The Provider wraps the App component in index.js.

Comment: If you don't show where the provider, sidebar, and login components are used we can't really answer your question.

Comment: I add code in the question. Do you need more info ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, the problem is that the Context in react is useful for components that are mounted at the same time. In our case we were trying to use the context in components that are not mounted at the same time, because the component "Sidebar" is loaded after the user logs in "Login". So when the user logs in, the pages are reloaded and "Sidebar" is mounted, when this happens the context restarts and loses the values that had been updated in the "Login" component.